# rails 2.3.8 + actionwebservice + ruby 1.9.2 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hello I'm trying to use rails 2.3.8 + actionwebservice . With ruby 1.8.7 it's ok, but when I switch to 1.9.2 I have next error
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails2/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require': no such file to load -- soap/rpc/driver (MissingSourceFile)

gemfile :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem "rails", "2.3.8"
gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
gem "mysql2"
gem 'athlite-actionwebservice', :require => 'actionwebservice', :git => "git://github.com/athlite/actionwebservice.git"
```

gem -v
1.8.6

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soap driver that was available in ruby 1.8 has been removed in ruby 1.9

You'll need to build soap for ruby 1.9 yourself as outlined in this answer: [Using SOAP and other Standard Libraries in Ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878388/using-soap-and-other-standard-libraries-in-ruby-1-9-2)