# How do I move from SOAP:RPC:Driver to Savon

Tags: ruby, soap, rpc, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

As [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856698/rails-2-3-8-actionwebservice-ruby-1-9-2-problem) [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878388/using-soap-and-other-standard-libraries-in-ruby-1-9-2) the `SOAP::RPC::Driver` which was available in Ruby 1.8 has been removed in Ruby 1.9. People [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2217268/21115) using the [Savon gem](http://savonrb.com/), but I can't find any tutorials on how to convert existing code, specifically for endpoints for which there is no WSDL available.

For example, with `SOAP::RPC::Driver` we could write:

```
require 'soap/rpc/driver'
client = SOAP::RPC::Driver.new 'http://example.com/endpoint', 'MY_NAMESPACE'
```

Add methods (since in my case I have no WSDL available):

```
client.add_method 'MyMethod', 'Arg1', 'Arg2'
```

And then call them:

```
response = client.MyMethod arg_one arg_two
```

I don't see how to add methods like this with Savon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [not using a WSDL](http://savonrb.com/#-not-using-a-wsdl) one must set up `wsdl` explicitly (I find this a little counter-intuitive, but it works):

```
require 'savon'
client = Savon::Client.new do
    wsdl.endpoint = 'http://example.com/endpoint'
    wsdl.namespace = 'MY_NAMESPACE'; 
end
```

I don't believe there is an equivalent to `add_method` in Savon, but you should then be able to make a request thus:

```
response = client.request 'MyMethod' do
  soap.body = { 'Arg1' => arg_one' }
end
```

However when I did this I received the following error:

```
Savon::SOAP::Fault: (SOAP-ENV:Client) SOAPAction shall match 'uri#method' if present
```

I was able to work around this by explicitly setting `SOAPAction`:

```
response = client.request 'MyMethod', soap_action: '#MyMethod' do ...
```

Finally I got this error:

```
Savon::SOAP::Fault: (SOAP-ENV:Client) Denied access to method (MyMethod) in class (main) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/SOAP/Lite.pm line 2128.
```

This seems to be because the given `wsdl.namespace` isn't passed as expected with the request. I was able to resolve this by explicitly setting it in both `soap_action` and `xmlns`:

```
response = client.request 'MyMethod', soap_action: 'MY_NAMESPACE#MyMethod', xmlns: 'MY_NAMESPACE'
```